# CmisInvalidArgumentException when downloading Private Working Copy from Alfresco via CMIS

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

My [open-source app](http://CmisSync.com) downloads the files of an [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com) folder (by [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services)).
Algorithm is very simple:

1. List content of folder with [Folder.getChildren()](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.8.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Folder.html#getChildren%28%29)
2. Download each with [Document.getContentStream()](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.8.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Document.html#getContentStream%28%29)

It works fine, except for folders that contain a [Working Copy](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/cuh-content-workingcopy.html) of a file, in which case Alfresco says:

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisInvalidArgumentException: Stream id is invalid: workspace://SpacesStore/8b9a58ba-652f-4a18-8d26-aba06df98d25;pwc
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISConnector.getContentStream(CMISConnector.java:1199)
    at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.getContentStream(AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.java:1795)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor700.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

The `;pwc` probably means "Private Working Copy", which is a special case in the CMIS protocol. Working Copies are created when an Alfresco Share user clicks "Edit Offline" on a document (aka check out/check in).

Is my algorithm flawed? Or could it be a bug in Alfresco/OpenCMIS?

Comment: Can you not just filter out the working copies, and only do your work via the master node?

Comment: @Gagravarr: I thought about doing it, but I need to download everything because these files might be needed too, I believe. It is also by curiousity: the fact that download is allowed by the client library seems to imply that downloading those kind of files should work too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the details, as you don't paste here the code that triggers the exception and you don't mention which Chemistry version you're using. Anyway, if I run the following groovy code within the [CMIS workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) v0.8.0 it successfully print all files contents:

```
def obj = session.getObjectByPath("/cc");
def children = obj.getChildren();
for (doc in children) {
  def s = doc.getContentStream();
  def i = s.getStream();
  println(i.text);
}
```

The `cc` folder used above is one I created in [Alfresco CMIS instance](http://cmis.alfresco.com), where I put a file and checked it out to create a PWC. I assume there is some issue with your code, as the above code uses the very same API.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the investigation! My code is actually public, but I will try to shorten it into a quickly graspable snippet. Hopefully doing so will help me find a bug in my code.